# How to create Network Security Group for all subnets in loop with Terraform on Azure

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform0.12+, azure-rm

**Objective**: Trying to create `network security group` for all `subnets` in vnet in Azure via `Terraform` with loop

Code that I am using:

**Main.tf:**

```
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "nsg" {
  for_each            = var.subnets
  name                = lower("nsg_${each.key}_in")
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  location            = var.location
  tags                = merge({ "ResourceName" = lower("nsg_${each.key}_in") }, var.tags, )
  dynamic "security_rule" {
    for_each = concat(lookup(each.value, "nsg_inbound_rules", []), lookup(each.value, "nsg_outbound_rules", []))
    content {
      name                       = security_rule.value[0] == "" ? "Default_Rule" : security_rule.value[0]
      priority                   = security_rule.value[1]
      direction                  = security_rule.value[2] == "" ? "Inbound" : security_rule.value[2]
      access                     = security_rule.value[3] == "" ? "Allow" : security_rule.value[3]
      protocol                   = security_rule.value[4] == "" ? "Tcp" : security_rule.value[4]
      source_port_range          = "*"
      destination_port_range     = security_rule.value[5] == "" ? "*" : security_rule.value[5]
      source_address_prefix      = security_rule.value[6] == "" ? element(each.value.subnet_address_prefix, 0) : security_rule.value[6]
      destination_address_prefix = security_rule.value[7] == "" ? element(each.value.subnet_address_prefix, 0) : security_rule.value[7]
      description                = "${security_rule.value[2]}_Port_${security_rule.value[5]}"
    }
  }
}
resource "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" "nsg-assoc" {
  for_each                  = var.subnets
  subnet_id                 = azurerm_subnet.snet[each.key].id
  network_security_group_id = azurerm_network_security_group.nsg[each.key].id
}
```

**variables.tf:**

```
variable "subnets" {
  type = map(object({
    name    = string
  }))

  default = {
    "s1" = { name = "dns_snet"},
    "s2" = { name = "common_snet"},
    "s3" = { name = "gw_snet"},
    "s4" = { name = "clientdata_snet"}
}
}
```

**Error I am getting**

```
Error: Unsupported attribute
│ 
│   on main.tf line 167, in resource "azurerm_subnet" "snet":
│  167:   name                 = lower(format("snet-%s-${var.hub_vnet_name}-${var.location}", each.value.subnet_name))
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.value is object with 1 attribute "name"
│ 
│ This object does not have an attribute named "subnet_name"
```

Please suggest where I am doing mistake ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your variable `subnets` only have the attribute **name**, so you need to update `each.value.subnet_name` to `each.value.name`

Comment: The error message states the cause is in `azurerm_subnet.snet`, but that resource config is not provided in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reproduce in my environment, Its working fine. Below is the code you can make use of it and do changes in names of variables as per your requirement.

**main.tf**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features{}
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name = "v-rasXXXXree"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "example-network"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]

  tags = {
    environment = "Production"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "snet" {
  for_each = var.subnets
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  name = each.value["name"]
  address_prefixes = each.value["address_prefixes"]
}



resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "nsg" {
  for_each            = var.subnets
  name                = lower("nsg_${each.key}_in")
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  #tags                = merge({ "ResourceName" = lower("nsg_${each.key}_in") }, var.tags, )
  dynamic "security_rule" {
    for_each = concat(lookup(each.value, "nsg_inbound_rules", []), lookup(each.value, "nsg_outbound_rules", []))
    content {
      name                       = security_rule.value[0] == "" ? "Default_Rule" : security_rule.value[0]
      priority                   = security_rule.value[1]
      direction                  = security_rule.value[2] == "" ? "Inbound" : security_rule.value[2]
      access                     = security_rule.value[3] == "" ? "Allow" : security_rule.value[3]
      protocol                   = security_rule.value[4] == "" ? "Tcp" : security_rule.value[4]
      source_port_range          = "*"
      destination_port_range     = security_rule.value[5] == "" ? "*" : security_rule.value[5]
      source_address_prefix      = security_rule.value[6] == "" ? element(each.value.subnet_address_prefix, 0) : security_rule.value[6]
      destination_address_prefix = security_rule.value[7] == "" ? element(each.value.subnet_address_prefix, 0) : security_rule.value[7]
      description                = "${security_rule.value[2]}_Port_${security_rule.value[5]}"
    }
  }
}
resource "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" "nsg-assoc" {
  for_each                  = var.subnets
  subnet_id                 = azurerm_subnet.snet[each.key].id
  network_security_group_id = azurerm_network_security_group.nsg[each.key].id
}
```

**variable.tf**

```
variable "subnets" {
  type=map(any)
  default = {
    subnet_1 = {
        name="subnet_1"
        address_prefixes=["10.0.1.0/24"]
    }
    subnet_2={
        name="subnet-2"
        address_prefixes=["10.0.2.0/24"]
    }
    subnet_3={
        name="subnet_3"
        address_prefixes=["10.0.3.0/24"]
    }
  }
}
```

**Ouput**

[image]

[image]